# AES 128 Encryption in Angular 4 and decryption in Java

Tags: java, angular, aes, cryptojs

I am using a CryptoJS(AES) for encryption in Angular 4 using below code:

```
const key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('7061737323313233');
const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('7061737323313233');
const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt('String to encrypt', key, {
  keySize: 16,
  iv: iv,
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
  padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});
console.log('Encrypted :' + encrypted);
```

and below java code to decrypt using AES:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Encryption {

private static SecretKeySpec secretKey;
private static byte[] key;

public static void setKey(String myKey)
{
    MessageDigest sha = null;
    try {
        key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
        sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        key = sha.digest(key);
        key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
        secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt, String secret)
{
    try
    {
        setKey(secret);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}

public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt, String secret)
{
    try
    {
        setKey(secret);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error while decrypting: " + e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
 }
```

and

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String secretKey = "7061737323313233";
    String originalString = "Response from angular";
    String decryptedString = Encryption.decrypt(originalString, secretKey);
    System.out.println(decryptedString);
}
 }
```

Angular and java both code works fine if i run it independently for Encryption and Decryption. but when i encrypt using angular and decrypt using java it gives error:

> Error while decrypting: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded

Now my issues are there is a diffrence of padding in angular and java. In angular it is Pkcs7 and in java it is Pkcs5 but this link [Padding](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9043/what-is-the-difference-between-pkcs5-padding-and-pkcs7-padding)
says both are same then, why this error is comming. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

My code to generate key was generating bad key in java. So i changed it to :

```
 Key key = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"),"AES" );
```

Now its working fine

Comment: btw I hope this is only to learn and you understand that having static key and iv is a very bad idea

Comment: @gusto2 yes it is just to learn i will use dynamic key and iv.

Comment: @Rider, could you please tell me how you achieved encryption and decryption on angular and java sides.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little problematic because of the difference in Javascript and Java libraries.

Please follow the below code which worked for me and I was successfully able to encrypt the data in Java and decrypt in Java.

```java
import java.security.Key;
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Crypt {

    private static final String ALGO = "AES"; // Default uses ECB PKCS5Padding

    public static String encrypt(String Data, String secret) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey(secret);
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
        String encryptedValue = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encVal);
        return encryptedValue;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt, String secret) {

        try {
            Key key = generateKey(secret);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error while decrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static Key generateKey(String secret) throws Exception {
        byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(secret.getBytes());
        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(decoded, ALGO);
        return key;
    }

    public static String decodeKey(String str) {
        byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(str.getBytes());
        return new String(decoded);
    }

    public static String encodeKey(String str) {
        byte[] encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(str.getBytes());
        return new String(encoded);
    }

    public static void main(String a[]) throws Exception {
        /*
         * Secret Key must be in the form of 16 byte like,
         *
         * private static final byte[] secretKey = new byte[] { ‘m’, ‘u’, ‘s’, ‘t’, ‘b’,
         * ‘e’, ‘1’, ‘6’, ‘b’, ‘y’, ‘t’,’e’, ‘s’, ‘k’, ‘e’, ‘y’};
         *
         * below is the direct 16byte string we can use
         */
        String secretKey = "mustbe16byteskey";
        String encodedBase64Key = encodeKey(secretKey);
        System.out.println("EncodedBase64Key = " + encodedBase64Key); // This need to be share between client and server

        // To check actual key from encoded base 64 secretKey
        // String toDecodeBase64Key = decodeKey(encodedBase64Key);
        // System.out.println("toDecodeBase64Key = "+toDecodeBase64Key);
        String toEncrypt = "Please encrypt this message!";
        System.out.println("Plain text = " + toEncrypt);

        // AES Encryption based on above secretKey
        String encrStr = Crypt.encrypt(toEncrypt, encodedBase64Key);
        System.out.println("Cipher Text: Encryption of str = " + encrStr);

        // AES Decryption based on above secretKey
        String decrStr = Crypt.decrypt(encrStr, encodedBase64Key);
        System.out.println("Decryption of str = " + decrStr);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <h2>Java JavaScript Encryption & Decryption</h2>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log('crypto - js’, CryptoJS);
        var encryptedBase64Key = 'bXVzdGJlMTZieXRlc2tleQ==’;
        var parsedBase64Key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encryptedBase64Key);
        var encryptedData = null;
        {
            // Encryption process
            var plaintText = "Please encrypt this message!”;
            // console.log( "plaintText = " + plaintText );
            // this is Base64-encoded encrypted data
            encryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintText, parsedBase64Key, {
                mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
                padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
            });
            console.log("encryptedData = " + encryptedData);
        }
        {
            // Decryption process
            var encryptedCipherText = 'U2WvSc8oTur1KkrB6VGNDmA3XxJb9cC+T9RnqT4kD90=’; // or encryptedData;
            var decryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedCipherText, parsedBase64Key, {
                mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
                padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
            });
            // console.log( "DecryptedData = " + decryptedData );
            // this is the decrypted data as a string
            var decryptedText = decryptedData.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
            console.log("DecryptedText = " + decryptedText);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```